# Is it possible to use Cells in the formula

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, excel-formula

I need each cell on the next row (a loop is executed) to have protection from entering numeric values, only letters. There is a code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(iLastRow, 16).Select
  With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=ISTEXT(P3)"

  End With
```

```
Formula1:="=ISTEXT(Cells((iLastRow, 16))"
```

Comment: xlBetween, Formula1:="=ISTEXT(P" & iLastRowNow & ")" - it helped, but it turned out that if the numbers are not at the beginning, the formula takes them for text values, and you need to get rid of them altogether

Comment: Numbers can be text so IsText() is useless. Function must examine every character in string to determine if any are numbers. Review https://trumpexcel.com/extract-numbers-from-string-excel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"=ISTEXT(" & Cells(iLastRow, 16) & ")"
```

This is for your reference only.